# Tomcat does not deploy my web projects in Eclipse 2023-06

Tags: eclipse, tomcat9

I am on an Ubuntu18.04, Tomcat9.0, JDK8, and Eclipse 2023-06 platform.
I upgraded to a new PC from Ubuntu16.04 and Tomcat7, JDK8 which worked fine.
When I right click my project (with path LDS5.0) and debug on server, there is the "Requested resource is not available".
However it has a Context entry in the  section of server.xml

```
  <Context docBase="W-LDS3.5.18" path="/LDS3.5" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:W-LDS3.5.18"/>
```

But when I open the tomcat manager,the application with path LDS3.5 is shown as running, but not deployed.

Also Eclipse creates and empty directory W-LDS3.5.18 in the tomcat/webapps folder.

I cannot understand what is going on.

I upgraded Eclipse from 2019 to 2023 - did not help.
I checked permissions and the tomcat folder and set them to rwx for others in case it was a permissions problem.
I have "takes control of Tomcat installation" set in the eclipse server.
The startup log does not even refer to the W-LDS3.5.18 project at all which is very odd given the  entry in server.xml.

**UPDATE**

I thought it was maybe the new linux installation causing the problem so I installed everything on my windows machine.  Unbelievably, all started out fine and Tomcat loaded the app.  Then for some reason it started doing the same thing - ignoring the app and not loading it.  The only thing I did between it working and not (I think) was to edit my AppInit.java file which is the initializer for the app.

Anyone got any ideas about this as I cannot move until I can get it to work.

Comment: What would also be good would be if somebody can explain exactly how eclipse launches tomcat.  I note that the tomcat service is not running but netstat tells me that localhost:8080 is being listened to by a java app, which I assume is eclipse.  But more detail would definitely help.  For example, is a .war file produced first which is put into the tomcat webapps folder before it is launched so it is auto deployed (although I cannot see it) or what?

Comment: In the server editor where you selected "takes control of Tomcat installation", there's a text field showing where your web apps will be deployed. Look there. It's not making war files. Where is this Tomcat installation located? What kind of project are you deploying and what is its layout? Have you tried options other than the one that "takes control of Tomcat installation" to make *sure* that it isn't a permission problem of some kind that you've overlooked?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I checked in the deployment location:  wtpwebapps in the tomcat folder and note that eclipse created empty folders with names equal to my web app projects.  I assume these should contain the compiled code before tomcat starts.

Comment: The windows version created the directory structure and copied in the lib files but produced no .class files!